# Three tangents meet opposite edges in collinear points

Tags: geometry

The tangents at points $A$, $B$, and $C$ to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ meet the lines $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ at $M$, $N$, $P$.

Show that $M$, $N$ and $P$ are collinear.

I know I have to use radical axis but I just don't know where to start or how to draw it.

Comment: You can use Menelaus Theorem. If you can't solve, then I can find somethings for you. Have a good day.

Comment: @scarface can you explian how to use menalous ??

Comment: I have added the proof with using Menelaus Theorem. Stay in peace.

Comment: Also note that in [Collinearity Question using Menelaus' Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386877/35416), [DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/418563/deltascuti-fomalhautb) suggested [a cut-the-knot webpage](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/3Tangents.shtml) with a [Menelaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem)-based proof for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also this problem is a special case of homothety centres and homothety line. Three of any homothetic figures are given. In pairs [homothety centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_center) of these are collinear. Especially, three circles are homothetic in pairs. Intersections of tangent lines are homothety centres. So, they're collinear.

Furthermore, OP well known [Monge Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%27s_theorem#Proofs). (Link including a proof of it).

More and moreover, in Challenging Problems in Geometry (Alfred S. Posamentier, Charles T. Salkind) at pages 189-190:

[image: monge proof]

Answer (score 3):

What makes you say “I know I have to use radical axis”?

Personally I'd treat this as a special case of [Pascal's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem), if you can build on that:

[image: Pascal's theorem configuration]

Pascal's theorem states that given all the other incidences, the three points $M,N,P$ will be collinear in the above situation. Now you can imagine moving $A_1$ and $A_2$ closer together. In the limit, when they are the same point, the line connecting them will have become a tangent. Likewise for the other two. So all the dark blue lines would become tangents, all the cyan ones are opposite connecting lines. It doesn't even have to be a circle, any conic will do.