# Tricky circle+triangle geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, alternative-proof

*This was a problem in my coaching study material.*

**Tangents to circumcircle of ∆ABC at points A,B,C meet the sides BC,CA,AB at points P,Q,R respectively. Prove that P,Q,R are collinear.**

I tried joining pq , qr , rq and proving sum of any two is equal to third but only things were getting messy, coordinate geometry also couldnt help. Any help is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: diagram might help

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250537/three-tangents-meet-opposite-edges-in-collinear-points